# SQL server database, Select a List of Model A depending on some entries in another List

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq

I hope I sound Understandable, 
I have this database table:

**Courses**

```
public Course()
    {
        EnrolledStudentsEmails = new HashSet<string>();
    }

    [Key]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

    public ICollection<string> EnrolledStudentsEmails { get; set; }//Normal String Collection - Not Foreign Keys
```

Using LINQ, I want to:

Select All Courses where Student email = example@123.com

How is that possible, Using Entity Framework 6, LINQ-to-Entity

Comment: Linq-to-Objects or Linq-to-Entities? Is this EF4/EF5/EF6 or EFCore?

Comment: List-to-Objects, EF6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's Linq-to-Objects (no Entity Framework) then it's straightforward:

```
IEnumerable<Course> courses = db.Courses
    .Where( c => c.EnrolledStudentsEmails.Contains("example@123.com" ) );
```

If it's Linq-to-Entities then you would use the defined relationship between `Students` and `Courses` by finding the `Student` first, then getting their `Courses`:

```
IQueryable<Course> query = db.Students
    .Where( student => student.Email == "example@123.com" )
    .SelectMany( student => student.Courses );
```

Or if you have a `Student` entity ready already:

```
Student student = db.Students.Single( s => s.Email == "example@123.com" );
IQueryable<Course> query = student.Courses;
```

(Note that the above will retrieve the entire `Student` entity and then the courses using lazy-loading, whereas the middle query will only load `Courses` and skip loading any `Student` data as the query will be executed by the database system).

Comment: @NasriYatim I have amended my answer. I am making assumptions about your database and entity schema which you did not provide in your original question.

Comment: I Understand, But following your assumptions it works perfectly. Thanks a lot!